# Add variable to session with click on the link.

Tags: php, session

I have working, but not safe script running. Basically, i have a loop that pulls "id" from db and diplays this code as final.

`<a href=next-page.php&lang_id=1&id=145> <img src=thumb1.jpg> </a>
<a href=next-page.php&lang_id=1&id=146> <img src=thumb2.jpg> </a>
<a href=next-page.php&lang_id=1&id=147> <img src=thumb3.jpg> </a>` etc.

When user clicks, he goes to next page and he can see full set of pictures from the event.
Thinking the passing variables in sessions might be the safest way to do it, i wish to change my script and remove "id" from the link, but i don't know how to pass add the "id" into session when user clics on the link.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @mareckmareck.
Create form and inside that form place radio button sets like following

```
<form action="next-page.php?lang_id=1" method="post">
  <p><input type="radio" name="option" value="145" /> <img src=thumb1.jpg></p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="option" value="146" /> <img src=thumb2.jpg></p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="option" value="147" /> <img src=thumb3.jpg></p>
</form>
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: I don;t want user to click two times in order to open next page... maybe i'll try with hidden field

Comment: Consider using javascript/jquery to handle it if you are not restricted.

Comment: You can add javascript code to trigger post on clicking on any radio button. in that way user has to only click once. hidden field is also one of the way to do that

Answer (score 1):

Use forms and `$_POST` instead. There is no need to pass such variables in `session`. Despite, you can not really do what you want in pure php/html without `form` or putting the id in URL in a logical manner.

Honestly though, it's not so bad to pass id in URL, if you have security checks on server side. You should try to use obfuscation of some sort, like a hash or business id (fake ID number, for example created in user context, so every user has his own IDs and they're not unique on their own). In fact it is best to not ever show database IDs to the user on the client side.

Comment: idea was to prevent malicious user to do SQL injection. Beacuse, now they can open 'next-page.php&lang_id=1&id=14'5' and get an error and work on that..

Comment: You can handle SQL injection on server side, if you properly escape the string you get. Though of course it's safer to pass data in other way if you use it in database operations.